# Target minor OS X build

Tags: xcode, macos

Xcode 7.2 supports targeting OS X 10.11.2, however the SDK is marked as just 10.11 (according to SDKSettings.plist, settings, etc.). I need to specifically target 10.11.2 as my min version because of some critical bug fixes, but I get a ton of warnings that it's higher than the active SDK, 10.11. Everything works fine, I'd just rather not see 200+ linker warnings, and I'm not sure if this will be an issue on the Mac App Store.

Anyone know why Apple doesn't mark their OS X SDKs with the build number when that's the thing that changes between minor releases, and if there's an easy way to silence the warnings?

Comment: How are you setting the minimum target?

Comment: And what features of ".2" is it you want to use? Also what are the linker error messages you are getting?

Comment: There are a few bugs in the VPN API that we filed that were fixed in 10.11.2. Among the errors are "object file ... was built for newer OSX version (10.11.2) than being linked (10.11)" and "OS X Deployment target '10.11.2' is newer than SDK 'OS X 10.11' in target foo".

Comment: I should have said "among the _warnings_" not errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what looks to be an acceptable solution: Use LSMinimumSystemVersion in my info.plist to specify 10.11.2 and leave the deployment target setting at 10.11. This results in my app being blocked at runtime with a friendly enough message and gets rid of all of the build warnings.

I don't know yet how it'll play on the app store, whether you'd be able to install it on 10.11.0 or .1, but worst case it's a short-term problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did `LSMinimumSystemVersion` prevent users with lesser versions from installing it from the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK / Deployment Target system works in terms of SDK versions. There's no change in SDK version between 10.11.0 and 10.11.2. SDK versions change only when the *APIs* in an SDK changes, not when the underlying behavior of those APIs changes. So you can't use SDK versioning to target your app to a minor/bugfix release.

It's certainly possible to check the OS X version at runtime and warn the user if running on a non-current 10.11.x build, though.

Comment: Thanks - A runtime check may be what I need to do. I was hoping to take advantage of an approach that would block installs, though. It's interesting that the iOS SDK version tracks with Xcode (7.0/9.0, 7.1/9.1, 7.2/9.2) while the OS X SDK doesn't. And according to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016630-SW1) there are some _minor_ API changes in 10.11.2, although they're just new constant values and they show up as  __MAC_10_11 in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the sdk major version isn't concerned with at all with features, but binary compatibility (what the ABI looks like, if it supports weak properties, what the obj-c runtime is), and what XIB features are supported, etc.

Since Objective-C has a pretty dynamic runtime, if you need a class you should see if you get one back from `NSClassFromString()`... if you need to see if an object supports a method, you should test with `-(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)`...

if you just want to not run at all then there are the `info.plist` keys... but you also shouldn't use the deployment version to prevent code from running on os's that are too old, the info.plist values are checked first and give the launching app (usually finder, or launch services) a chance to deliver a proper well formatted error, rather than just crash...

of course that value can be changed by a user... so you can also check the major/minor versions in the early code path of your app...

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar position to the OP. In case of my application, there was one small but significant change that Apple have introduced in 10.11.2. This version of El Cap came with a newer version of libnetsnmp which my app depends on, and which has changed one of the data types definitions from uint32_t to u_long.

I've not tested this yet in the Mac App Store, but it seems I can change the OSX Deployment Target in the Project to 10.11.2 but leave the Deployment Info for my Target set to the default 10.11. When I compile my app configured this way, I get no more linker warnings.

Please note - I have not tested this against the Mac App Store yet.